# PostgreSQL: Exclude duplicates as sorted by another key

Tags: postgresql, window-functions

Consider the following table that stores update history of some attributes of certain objects, organized by `effective` and `published` dates:

```
create table update_history(
  obj_id integer,
  effective date,
  published date,
  attr1 text,
  attr2 integer,
  attr3 boolean,
  primary key(obj_id, effective, published)
);
insert into update_history values
  (1, '2021-01-01', '2021-01-01', 'foo', null, null),
  (1, '2021-01-01', '2021-01-02', null, 1, false),
  (1, '2021-01-02', '2021-01-01', 'foo', 1, false),
  (1, '2021-01-02', '2021-01-02', 'bar', 1, false),
  (1, '2021-01-03', '2021-01-01', 'bar', 1, true),
  (1, '2021-01-04', '2021-01-01', 'bar', 1, true),
  (1, '2021-01-05', '2021-01-01', 'bar', 2, true),
  (1, '2021-01-05', '2021-01-02', 'bar', 1, true),
  (1, '2021-01-05', '2021-01-03', 'bar', 1, true),
  (1, '2021-01-06', '2021-01-04', 'bar', 1, true)
;
```

I need to write a PostgreSQL query that will simplify the history view for a given `obj_id` by excluding those update records that did *not* change any attributes from the immediately preceding update as ordered by `effective` and `published` columns. In essence those would be rows ## 6, 9 and 10, marked in *italic* in the table below:

| # | obj_id | effective | published | attr1 | attr2 | attr3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | 1 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-01-01 | foo | (null) | (null) |
| **2** | 1 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-01-02 | (null) | 1 | false |
| **3** | 1 | 2021-01-02 | 2021-01-01 | foo | 1 | false |
| **4** | 1 | 2021-01-02 | 2021-01-02 | bar | 1 | false |
| **5** | 1 | 2021-01-03 | 2021-01-01 | bar | 1 | true |
| *6* | *1* | *2021-01-04* | *2021-01-01* | *bar* | *1* | *true* |
| **7** | 1 | 2021-01-05 | 2021-01-01 | bar | 2 | true |
| **8** | 1 | 2021-01-05 | 2021-01-02 | bar | 1 | true |
| *9* | *1* | *2021-01-05* | *2021-01-03* | *bar* | *1* | *true* |
| *10* | *1* | *2021-01-06* | *2021-01-04* | *bar* | *1* | *true* |

Keep in mind that in the real life case there are way more attributes to deal with and I don't want the query to get too messy.

The closest I got to the desired result was using the `rank` window function:

```
select
  obj_id, effective, published,
  attr1, attr2, attr3
from (
  select *,
    rank() over (
      partition by attr1, attr2, attr3
      order by effective, published
    ) as rank
  from update_history
  where obj_id = 1) as d
where rank = 1
order by effective, published;
```

That results in this:

| obj_id | effective | published | attr1 | attr2 | attr3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-01-01 | foo | (null) | (null) |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-01-02 | (null) | 1 | false |
| 1 | 2021-01-02 | 2021-01-01 | foo | 1 | false |
| 1 | 2021-01-02 | 2021-01-02 | bar | 1 | false |
| 1 | 2021-01-03 | 2021-01-01 | bar | 1 | true |
| 1 | 2021-01-05 | 2021-01-01 | bar | 2 | true |

As you can see, row #8 from the original table is erroneously excluded, although it changed `attr2` from the its previous row, #7. Apparently, the problem is that partitioning is applied before sorting in the window definition.

I wonder if there is another way to accomplish this with a single PostgresSQL query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the `lag()` for this:

```
select *
from (
  select obj_id, effective, published,
         attr1, attr2, attr3, 
         (attr1, attr2, attr3) is distinct from lag( (attr1,attr2,attr3) ) over (partition by obj_id order by effective, published) as is_different
  from update_history
) t
where is_different
```